# Unable to return a Row that contains xmldata from two joined views Oracle

Tags: oracle

I've got two views that have similar values. I'm attempting to return a row using a where clause however, no data is returning.

If I do a select * without the where clause, data is returned.

Order1 View:

```
CREATE VIEW AS Order1 SELECT OrderNumber, CAST(Longitude*16/180 AS number(38)) 
AS MapGridX1, CAST(Latitude*16/90 AS number(38)) AS MapGridY1, OrderData 
FROM Order LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderAssociation ON Order.Id = OrderAssociation.OrderId;
```

Order2 View

```
CREATE VIEW AS Order2 SELECT OrderNumber, CAST(Longitude*16/180 AS number(38)) 
AS MapGridX1, CAST(Latitude*16/90 AS number(38)) AS MapGridY1, OrderData 
FROM Order LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderAssociation ON Order.Id = OrderAssociation.OrderId;
```

SQL Call:

```
select Order2.* from Order2 join Order1 on Order2.Id = Order1.Id where Order2.MapGridX1 = 8
```

Order1 Table: 
Id: 1 
OrderData: {XMLDATA}
MapGridX1: 8
MapGridY1: 90

Order2 Table: 
Id: 1 
OrderData: {XMLDATA}
MapGridX1: 8
MapGridY1: 90

Comment: when you execute the where clause on each views individually , is it returning the right data?

Comment: Yes, on the individual view, i'm able to return the correct data, only when these are joined, and then I use a where clause, i return no data. if no where clause is used, data is returned

Comment: something else  must be going on ..as i dont see anything wrong with your query...... so this query returns data you expect? `select Order2.* from Order2 join Order1 on Order2.Id = Order1.Id`

Comment: Yep, that'll return data, as soon as the where is included, no data is returned